# CSS Height Messing Up

Tags: css

I am having a terrible time getting my height of my DIVs to properly scale with the height of the DIV's containted inside of them.  Currently the DIVs that contain other content DIVS are not set to any specific height, but for some reason they have a height way beyond the content that is contained in them (which currently isn't anything)

Here is the link:
http://www.brockpatterson.com/secret.php

As you can see, the 1st blue area is super tall, and the lighter blue area below is the same.  I'm not sure if some other CSS element is messing with it.  I've been looking at it and messing with different perameters for a few hours now.

Thanks,
drummer

Comment: Use Firebug to inspect the computed styles for the relevant divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#content_container` is set to 100% height.  Remove that and you'll be fine.

Comment: Also you have two divs with the ID 'content_container'. You should use classes for that

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `height: 100%` at `#content_container`?

(Also, you should never have two HTML elements with the same ID...)

Comment: yes sir, I had done that temporarily!  I do appreciate you telling me anyways because I might not have known! haha =)